# how does the yetzer hara rule over a person?

Tags: ramchal, evil-inclination

In the "Path of the Just" chapter 5, Rabbi Luzzato writes:

> For in truth, the evil inclination (yetzer hara) is very powerful in a man. Without
>   a man's knowledge, it advances and strengthens over him and comes to
>   rule over him.
>
> הנה היצר הרע באמת חזק הוא באדם מאד, ומבלי ידיעתו של האדם הולך הוא
>   ומתגבר בו ושולט עליו

what is this "ruling over him" he refers to, and how does the yetzer hara accomplish this? please source from chazal (talmud, rishonim, ramchal, maharal, etc.)

Comment: Why do you assume it means anything other than causing man to sin?

Answer (score 1):

It seems through רוח שטות

The  spirit of folly

Talmud.
https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.3a.4/he/Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli?lang=bi

http://www.jewishaz.com/religiouslife/torahstudy/judaism-s-definition-of-sin-spirit-of-folly/article_d624fc92-325b-11e6-8704-d7cfe7067e0d.html

Tanya in 6 places.
http://www.chabad.org/7893
http://www.chabad.org/7891/
http://www.chabad.org/7898/
http://www.chabad.org/7903/
http://www.chabad.org/7904/
http://www.chabad.org/7963/

Mishna Berurah
https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.4.47

PS
Midrash.
https://www.sefaria.org/Kohelet_Rabbah.4.13.1/he/Daat_Kohelet_Rabbah?lang=bi

http://www.hidabrut.com/video/128818/Rabbi-Yitzchak-Botton/Ethics-of-the-Fathers-(23)---Beware-of-the-Old-Foolish-King